# React useState() array not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have created new custom selectbox using React. There is pre-populated array which I am loading on component load (using useEffect). When user search for any non existing country there would be a option to add. So I used useState hooked. Code is as under :-

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
```

Countries list :-

```
[
  {"value": 1, "label": "Singapore"},
  {"value": 2, "label": "Malaysia"},
  {"value": 3, "label": "Indonesia"},
  {"value": 4, "label": "Phillipines"},
  {"value": 5, "label": "Thailand"},
  {"value": 6, "label": "India"},
  {"value": 7, "label": "Australia"},
  {"value": 8, "label": "Pakistan"}
]


const handleHTTPRequest = () => {
    service.getData() 
    .then(res => {
      setCountries(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleHTTPRequest()
  })
```

I am checking the searched country in the array and if not exists I simply add in array

```
const addCountry = (country) => {
    let isRecordExist = countries.filter(c => c.label === country).length > 0 ? true : false;
    const obj = {
      value: countries.length + 1,
      label: country
    }
    let updatedVal = [...countries, obj]
    
    setSelectedCountry(country)

    if (!isRecordExist) {
      **setCountries**(updatedVal) // updating array
    }
  }
```

The problem is its not updating although I can see data in updatedVal.

Entire code is here :-

https://github.com/ananddeepsingh/react-selectbox

Comment: I dont know why you are saying its not working, I have just tried it and it seems to be adding it properly in the list for me.

Comment: have you tried using my git repo. If possible can you please fork my git repo and test it. Might be I am doing something wrong

Comment: I cloned you're repo, installed all the dependencies and I have run it with yarn start...When I search for a place it does not exist, I can add it and it appears in the list as required.

Comment: In my repo. I did some thing wrong to make this works. So, if you go to line no 23 in App.js, I am directly updating array rather than using setCountries method. Please modify in your local and then run

Comment: The problem is not in App.js, it's in your select-box.js. Give me a minute to take a deeper look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the root problem. In your Select Box component you have:

```
 const [defaultValueoptions, setdefaultValueoptions] = useState(options);
```

It should be:

```
 const [defaultValueoptions, setdefaultValueoptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setdefaultValueoptions(options);
  }, [options]);
```

Comment: hey, I am not sure exactly what the problem is with your code as I did not have time to check all code but when you put a key on an element, everytime that key changes the element re-renders...and it will use the new state...voila! the problem might be better solved other way but in a time of need you do with what you can.

Comment: Although this hack works but its not updating the updated value with country object.

Answer (score 8):

The problem appears to be that you're passing to `useState()` the array (`updatedVal`) that has its reference unchanged, thus it appears to React that your data hasn't been modified and it [bails out without updating your state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update).

Try drop that unnecessary variable and do directly `setCountries([...countries, obj])`

Another minor fix about your code I may suggest: you may use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to make sure that every existing item has different `label`. It has two advantages over `.filter()` - it will stop looping right upon hitting duplicate (if one exists) and won't proceed till the end of array (as `.filter()` does), thus won't slow down unnecessarily re-render and it returns boolean, so you won't actually need extra variable for that.

Following is a quick demo of that approach:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const CountryList = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://run.mocky.io/v3/40a13c3b-436e-418c-85e3-d3884666ca05')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setCountries(data))
  }, [])
  
  const addCountry = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const countryName = new FormData(e.target).get('label')
    if(countries.every(({label}) => label != countryName))
      setCountries([
        ...countries,
        {
          label: countryName,
          value: countries.length+1
        }
      ])
    e.target.reset()
  }
  
  return !!countries.length && (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {
          countries.map(({value, label}) => (
            <li key={value}>{label}</li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
      <form onSubmit={addCountry}>
        <input name="label" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add country" />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

render (
  <CountryList />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @AnandDeepSingh : check out updated version of my answer, hopefully it gives you a clue

Comment: Thanks @Yevgen, it very interesting and thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not updating the countries list inside your `SelectBox` component. The countries list shouldn't be managed by the `App` component but by `SelectBox` component, as it's a stateful component. You are trying to get React to rerender your `SelectBox` component by changing the state of the `App` component, which won't work. Well it rerenders because you change a prop `options`, but it uses `defaultValueoptions` to display options, which you never update.

Add this to your `SelectBox` component:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setDefaultValueOptions(options);
}, [options]);
```

And change the line 9 to:

```js
const [defaultValueoptions, setDefaultValueOptions] = useState(options);
```

**EDIT**
I didn't see that Talmacel Marian Silviu had already edited his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63092808/828023